# Best practice regarding separating a substring between characters on Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Note: I tagged the `google-app-script` because that's where I work and I don't know if there might be some different nomenclatures that are important for everyone to know when answering the question.

Currently, to find the scores (in the example below it is `0-0`) that appear between fixed characters `'FT '` and `')'`, I do it this way:

```
var text = 'So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 0-0) its ours final score';
var length = text.length;
var find_str_ft = 'FT ';
var find_str_ft_length = find_str_ft.length;
var position = text.indexOf(find_str_ft);
var text_right = text.substring(position + find_str_ft_length, length);

var find_str_close_bar = ')';
var position_close_bar = text_right.indexOf(find_str_close_bar);
var text_left_close_bar = text_right.substring(0, position_close_bar);
Logger.log(text_left_close_bar);
```

log:

```
0-0
```

I understand that it is an archaic method and and i would like to know if there is more advanced and correct options to work with, even so that it doesn't take so many steps and/or so many lines of code for this.

Comment: Regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a capture group and match the digits with the hyphen, where the capture group 1 value is denoted by `m[1]` in the example code:

```
\(FT\s+(\d+-\d+)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `FT\s+` Match FT and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+-\d+)` Capture *group 1*, match 1+ digits `-` 1+ digits
- `\)` Match `)`

```js
const text = 'So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 0-0) its ours final score';
const m = text.match(/\(FT\s+(\d+-\d+)\)/);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

If there can be more occurrences using the `/g` flag:

```js
const text = 'So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 0-0) its ours final score, and not (FT 1-1)';
console.log(Array.from(text.matchAll(/\(FT\s+(\d+-\d+)\)/g), m => m[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's not the absolute best, and I can imagine places where it's impractical, but a generalized solution I like for many use cases is below:

```js
var str = 'BeginingoflongstringFToranystringScoreorwhateverwewant)oranystringEndoflongstring';
var first_filter = 'FToranystring';
var second_filter = ')oranystring';
var desired_string = str.slice(
  str.indexOf(first_filter) + first_filter.length,
  str.indexOf(second_filter),
);
console.log(desired_string);
```

And with your specific data we make one change, using `lastIndexOf`, rather than `indexOf` since it's a non-unique phrase in your string. To use it generally, it's best to only search for a string between two unique strings:

```js
var str = 'So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 0-0) its ours final score';
var first_filter = 'FT';
var second_filter = ')';
var desired_string = str.slice(
  str.indexOf(first_filter) + first_filter.length,
  str.lastIndexOf(second_filter),
);
console.log(desired_string);
```

Or, rather than just using the closing ")" in this case, you can use ") i":

```js
var str = 'So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 0-0) its ours final score';
var first_filter = 'FT';
var second_filter = ') i';
var desired_string = str.slice(
  str.indexOf(first_filter) + first_filter.length,
  str.indexOf(second_filter),
);
console.log(desired_string);
```

In any case it requires knowing your input string perfectly, so is rarely ideal.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression would make this very easy:

```
let text = 'So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 0-0) its ours final score';
let match = text.match(/\(FT\s+([^)]+)\)/);
let result = match[1];
```

You want to match the left side:

```
\(FT\s+
```

Which means match `(FT` and 1 or more whitespace characters.

Then you want to match the actual data that you want:

```
([^)]+)
```

This matches and captures any character that is not `)` (the end of our match) and that appears more than once.

Then you match the right side.

```
\)
```

Which is quite literally the `)` character.

Comment: Thanks @MinusFour for the attention and detail in your answer for my understanding of using each point of the `regular expression`

Answer (score 1):

#### Matching with regex

```
function lfunko() {
  let s = "So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 0-0) its ours final score";
  let m = s.match(/(?<=just )([^\)]+)|(?<=FT )([^\)]+)/g);
  Logger.log('First: %s Second: %s', m[0],m[1]);
}

Execution log
3:26:04 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:26:05 PM  Info    First: 1-2 Second: 0-0
3:26:05 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Utilizing two positive look behinds ored together.

If you wish to see some real expertise at such a match just add a **regex** tag and you will see some real masters of regular expressions.

Added Regex tag for you.  Wait for @Wiktor Stribiżew to answer before making your final selection.

Answer (score 1):

And one more for good measure...

```js
const text = 'So its (just 1-2) amazing (FT 7-10) its ours final score';
const regexScore = /FT\s+\d+-\d+/ig;
const regexDigits = /\d+/g
const found = text.match(regexScore);
const score = found[0].match(regexDigits);

console.log(found);
console.log(score);
```

Comment: The approach is very interesting, opening the way for the use of separate values in case it is necessary to use them. Thank you so much for opening up this field of vision!

Comment: Glad to help, Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternate Method:

You can also use [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method with [substr / substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), aside from using ***regex***:

## Script

```
function test() { //E.g. you have mustiple instances of "FT"
  var text = 'So its amazing (FT3-0 ) (just 1-2)  amazing (FT  0-0) its ours final score (FT 1-1  )';
  var match = text.split("FT");
  for(var i in match){
    if(i != 0){ //skip index 0 as it doesn't contain the score after every "FT" instance.
      Logger.log(match[i].trim().substr(0, 3)); //used trim to remove all white spaces before the substr method
    }
  }
}
```

## Result

[image]